# `selenium-webdriver` ruby gem cannot connect with chromedriver on Ubuntu 14.04

Tags: ruby, selenium, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

I'm running Ubuntu 16.04 and I'm trying to run a headless Chrome browser in ruby with `chromedriver`.

I've installed `chromedriver` on Ubuntu using [these instructions](https://christopher.su/2015/selenium-chromedriver-ubuntu/) and then I run this via the ruby `irb` console:

```
require 'selenium-webdriver'

options = Selenium::WebDriver::Chrome::Options.new
options.add_argument('--headless')

@driver = Selenium::WebDriver.for(:chrome, options: options)

Traceback (most recent call last):
   10: from /home/weefee/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.5.1/bin/irb:11:in `<main>'
    9: from (irb):5
    8: from /home/weefee/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.1/gems/selenium-webdriver-3.141.0/lib/selenium/webdriver.rb:86:in `for'
    7: from /home/weefee/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.1/gems/selenium-webdriver-3.141.0/lib/selenium/webdriver/common/driver.rb:44:in `for'
    6: from /home/weefee/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.1/gems/selenium-webdriver-3.141.0/lib/selenium/webdriver/common/driver.rb:44:in `new'
    5: from /home/weefee/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.1/gems/selenium-webdriver-3.141.0/lib/selenium/webdriver/chrome/driver.rb:44:in `initialize'
    4: from /home/weefee/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.1/gems/selenium-webdriver-3.141.0/lib/selenium/webdriver/common/service.rb:69:in `start'
    3: from /home/weefee/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.1/gems/selenium-webdriver-3.141.0/lib/selenium/webdriver/common/socket_lock.rb:39:in `locked'
    2: from /home/weefee/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.1/gems/selenium-webdriver-3.141.0/lib/selenium/webdriver/common/service.rb:72:in `block in start'
    1: from /home/weefee/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.1/gems/selenium-webdriver-3.141.0/lib/selenium/webdriver/common/service.rb:142:in `connect_until_stable'
Selenium::WebDriver::Error::WebDriverError (unable to connect to chromedriver 127.0.1.1:9515)
```

Any idea on how to fix it? A few notes:

1. Some people seem to encounter issues with `rbenv` and the shim that it sets up. I'm not using `rbenv` at all, so that's irrelevant here.
2. The above works when I try it on my OSx laptop. Of course there I can easily install chromedriver with `brew install chromedriver` and it just seems to work
3. Alternatively, I uninstalled chromedriver and re-installed it using the [chromedriver-helper](https://github.com/flavorjones/chromedriver-helper) gem. Still the same result.

I've been tearing my hair out for a while on this - any help would be appreciated. Thanks!

**UPDATE**

I dug deeper into the source of the `selenium-webdriver` gem to see exactly what it was doing when trying to connect to the `chromedriver` process.

I was able to replicate the following in my ruby console on the server using the same commands the `selenium-webdriver` gem uses:

```
#
# Start the Chromedriver Process
#

require 'childprocess'
process = ChildProcess.build(*["/usr/local/bin/chromedriver", "--port=9515"])
process.leader = true
process.alive? #=> false
process.start
process.alive? #=> true

#
# Create a Socket connection to 127.0.0.1:9515
#

require 'socket'
require 'selenium-webdriver'

host = Selenium::WebDriver::Platform.localhost                       #=> "127.0.1.1"
port = Integer(Selenium::WebDriver::Chrome::Service::DEFAULT_PORT)   #=> 9515
timeout = 5

# Create and connect to socket

addr     = Socket.getaddrinfo(host, port, Socket::AF_INET, Socket::SOCK_STREAM)
sock     = Socket.new(Socket::AF_INET, Socket::SOCK_STREAM, 0)
sockaddr = Socket.pack_sockaddr_in(port, addr[0][3])

# First need to rescue the writable error and then connect again
# to get the actual error. No idea why but even the official
# rubydocs use this pattern: https://apidock.com/ruby/Socket/connect_nonblock

begin
  sock.connect_nonblock(sockaddr)
rescue IO::WaitWritable
  IO.select(nil, [sock], nil, 5)
  sock.connect_nonblock(sockaddr)
end

#=> Errno::ECONNREFUSED (Connection refused - connect(2) for 127.0.1.1:9515)
```

So it seems the core error is that the socket refuses to connect on that (local) address and port, even though `chromedriver` is very much running on that port.

I don't know much about sockets at all - is this a common error?

Thanks!

Comment: It's working for me. I don't know what's the problem in your case. By the way use WATIR which is a wrapper around Ruby Selenium Binding.

Comment: One of my friend had same issue and upgraded chrome version and solved it! Give a try

Answer (score -2, accepted):

All the provided solutions were great recommendations, but ultimately tukan's answer led me down the path of carefully checking versions.

The setup I had didn't work on Ubuntu 14.04, which is about 5 years old at the time of this writing. **I re-built the whole thing on an Ubuntu 16.04 machine and it worked perfectly.**

I don't know *what* causes the error, but it seems to be something at the operating system level.

Answer (score 3):

I have tried it on the Ubuntu 16.04 (updated) and ruby which comes with the system `ruby 2.3.1p112 (2016-04-26) [x86_64-linux-gnu]`.

From what I guess is that you are using wrong, old (in the guide there is version **2.26** which will not work with current chrome), chromedriver, which is **not compatible** with the **current stable chrome**.

The current stable chrome is `Unpacking google-chrome-stable (71.0.3578.98-1) ...` and so you need to get chromedriver as close as possible to the chrome version.

To get complete list of chromedrivers' versions click [here](http://chromedriver.storage.googleapis.com/).

In my case that would be a `71.0.3578.80` version:

`wget -N http://chromedriver.storage.googleapis.com/71.0.3578.80/chromedriver_linux64.zip`

You can then continue as shown at the instructions.

Then you will get working `selenium-webdriver`:

```
irb
irb(main):001:0> require 'selenium-webdriver'
=> true
irb(main):003:0> options = Selenium::WebDriver::Chrome::Options.new
=> #<Selenium::WebDriver::Chrome::Options:0x00000002ee6db0 @args=#<Set: {}>, @binary=nil, @prefs={}, @extensions=[], @options={}, @emulation={}, @encoded_extensions=[]>
irb(main):004:0> options.add_argument('--headless')
=> #<Set: {"--headless"}>
irb(main):005:0> @driver = Selenium::WebDriver.for(:chrome, options: options)
=> #<Selenium::WebDriver::Chrome::Driver:0x..f95c429ee62a3a152 browser=:chrome>
```

Note: If you have issues installing `ffi` install `libffi-dev` via `apt-get`.

Comment: Very interesting. I tried updating to the same Google Chrome, Chrome, and Ruby version as you, and I still got the same error. The only thing I can think of that's a difference is I'm using Ubuntu 14.04 and you are using 16.04. I'll have to upgrade the OS at some point and try it - do you think that could be it? To be explicit, I'm using `Google Chrome 71.0.3578.98`, `ChromeDriver 71.0.3578.80`, `Ruby 2.3.1`, and `Ubuntu 14.04`

Comment: Yup, that was it. I replicated the entire installation on a different machine with Ubuntu 16.04 and it magically worked. Guess 14.04 is really too old at this point.

Comment: @user2490003 ah, you have different Ubuntu versions at your title and text.  I have taken the 16.04 version from the text `I'm running Ubuntu 16.04 and I'm ...`.  I did not test it on the older Ubuntu version.  I'm happy that it worked for you on the newer version.  I'll check with the 14.04 if I get my hands on it, I don't have it at my disposal at the moment.

Comment: That's my fault! I typed out `16.04` in the title by habit. I have now corrected it. I still awarded you the bounty since it was your work that led me to check the versions of everything and discover the OS version was important. Appreciate your help!

Comment: @user2490003 you are welcome.  I'm glad it worked out.

Answer (score 2):

```
wget -q -O - https://dl-ssl.google.com/linux/linux_signing_key.pub | sudo apt-key add -
sudo sh -c 'echo "deb [arch=amd64] http://dl.google.com/linux/chrome/deb stable main" >> /etc/apt/sources.list.d/google.list'
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get --only-upgrade install google-chrome-stable
```

This will keep your version up to date and available. I have had this solve similar problems that were encountered during CI testing. You should be able to setup your `@driver` afterwards.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. Unfortunately I already had the latest stable version installed so it didn't change anything. For what it's worth I'm using the following versions: `ChromeDriver 2.45.615279`, `Google Chrome 71.0.3578.98`, `ruby 2.5.1`, `selenium-webdriver-3.141.0`, all on `Ubuntu 14.04`,

Comment: Do I have to start the `chromedriver` server separately in the background, or are there any other dependencies I need?

Comment: I also used the `chromedriver-helper` gem.  Are you certain that you are installing the 64 bit version?

Comment: I had used the `webdriver` and `chromedrive-helper` gems at one point as well, but ran into the same issue. Is there a way I can confirm I'm using 64bit version? Also, I just posted an `UPDATE` to the question after doing some more research, hopefully that might shed a light on the problem. Thanks for your help!

Comment: `[arch=amd64]` in the 2nd command above would ensure the 64-bit.  If you are not using those commands I am not sure how you would verify.

Comment: @user2490003 `@driver = Selenium::WebDriver.for :chrome, switches: %w[--ignore-certificate-errors]`.  Can you try this and see if anything changes? It might just be a cert error.

Answer (score -1):

from this line:

```
Selenium::WebDriver::Error::WebDriverError (unable to connect to chromedriver 127.0.1.1:9515)
```

it suggests you are trying to connect to 127.0.1.1, while your localhost should be 127.0.0.1, could you check your configuration?

Comment: I corrected a typo in the question, but I think `127.0.1.1` is equaally valid and used by Ubuntu/Debian? See: https://askubuntu.com/a/754219/411497

Comment: try following to reinstall the WebDriver on ubuntu: 
`apt install chromium-chromedriver`
`ln -s /usr/lib/chromium-browser/chromedriver /usr/local/bin/chromedriver`